# Where is windows 11 math recognizer?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade, math-input-panel

I recently upgraded to windows 11 and there were a few features in windows 10 that are not there in windows 11. One of which is math input panel:

"Math Input Panel is removed. Math Recognizer will install on demand and includes the math input control and recognizer. Math inking in apps like OneNote"

I have been looking for the math recognizer app to pop up someday, and it's been over 2 months and it still hasn't shown up! I found the feature existing somewhere in settings and I am frustrated because it seems like math recognizer isn't actually an app. How to I access math recognizer, and can I use it like I used math input panel?

Comment: You have to install it.  You can install it within `Turn Windows Features On or Off`  You will have to provide a small portion of `DISM /online /get-capabilities` which lists Math Recognizer to answer this question if your unable to find it within `Turn Windows Features On or Off`

Comment: I have. Install it through the “Turn Windows Features On or Off” within Settings

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the command I provided, that includes the package, your attempting to install and I can submit an answer

Comment: Provided the output of the command then,.  What edition of Windows 11 are you using?

Comment: I am using windows version 21H2, I have no idea what you mean by "command". @Ramhound

Comment: I suggested a command that would generate a list of features that can be installed

Answer (score 1):

If this is still a thing:

Go to Settings -> Apps -> Optional Features, then make sure Math Recognizer is enabled