# How to install math input panel in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, math-input-panel

I want to install the Math input panel which lets you draw an equation and then copy/paste it into Word.

After upgrading to Windows 11 I can't  find it. Someone  said to turn it on from 'Turn Windows features on/off' but I can't seem to find it there.

Comment: What edition of Windows 11 do you have installed exactl[?](https://superuser.com/questions/1695659/where-is-windows-11-math-recognizer)

Answer (score 2):

if you go to **settings>apps>optional features** you can search for maths recogniser and if it isn't there you can install it using the add an optional feature button.
If you are having trouble finding it after that then you should be able to search for it in **settings>apps>apps & features**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).